# Getting position/degree on animate

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm trying to get the current position (between 0 and 360°) of `.me` during this animation :

http://jsfiddle.net/WcyyF/117/

So the hover out event doesn't start the animation from `0` but continues it from `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option with slightly less complex math is to track when the animation starts, and when it is interrupted.  Since it runs at a constant speed you can use the elapsed time to work out how many degrees each element should have traveled, and update the starting positions accordingly.  Roughly along the lines of:

```
var elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - this.startedAt;
var elapsedDegrees = Math.floor(360 * (elapsedTime / 20000));
$(".me").each(function() {
    $(this).attr('data', parseInt($(this).attr('data')) - elapsedDegrees + 360)
});
```

Here is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/WcyyF/120/

Comment: This solution works better with the other element on the page ty.

Answer (score 2):

Math will be involved.

You set their attr('data') with their start angle, so when you hover and stop, you will have to set all their angle again.

Here's the pseudo code:

```
length_x = $(this).position().left - center.left;
angle = arcos(length_x/radius);
$(this).attr('data') = angle;
```

Comment: It was slightly harder than this, but you put me on the right track : http://jsfiddle.net/WcyyF/119/. Thank you.